# sf polygon goes black in for loop in R

Tags: r, sp, sf

I'm making this loop, it's part of a script I'm making to illustrate a percentage in a polygon (let's say instead of a pie) but then I realized it looks good as an animation; when I start plotting, the polygon goes black every now and then, I want to be able to see the line between the two sections and with the black polygon I can't

```
library(units)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(osmdata)
library(spatial.tools)

xalver <- osmdata::getbb("xalapa veracruz", format_out = "sf_polygon")
ea <- sp::bbox(as(xalver, "Spatial"))
ea2 <- ea
for(i in seq(.001, .015, by = 0.001)) { 
  ea[4]  <-  ea[4] -i
  ea2[2] <- ea[4]
  oik <- bbox_to_SpatialPolygons(ea) %>% sf::st_as_sf() %>% st_set_crs(4326) 
  oik2 <- bbox_to_SpatialPolygons(ea2) %>% sf::st_as_sf() %>% st_set_crs(4326)
  anka <- rbind(oik, oik2)
  st_intersection(xalver, anka) %>% plot()
#st_area() -> osh

#  if( drop_units(osh[1])/drop_units(osh[2]) < 0.5) break
  Sys.sleep(.3)
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is that at certain points you are dividing the region into a single ring `POLYGON` and a multiple-ring `MULTIPOLYGON` object, because the slicing line is chopping two separate parts off the top of the region.

Since this vector now has different types of object in it, `sf` treats it as a generic `GEOMETRY` object - these objects can be mixes of lines, points, and polygons.

Because the `col` argument controls the line colour of lines and the fill colour of polygons, the choice was made to use black if plotting a `GEOMETRY` object. Hence if your intersection creates a mix of POLYGON and MULTIPOLYGON objects, everything is drawn with `col="black"`.

This is fixed in `sf` version 0.7.3 which is on github (but not yet on CRAN I think), where the code now tests the dimension of all elements in a `GEOMETRY` vector, and uses `col=NA` if the element is two dimensional (like a polygon).

Comment: plotting does work as i expected with geom_sf and plot.sf when there are two categories, so i'll try installing the dev version

Answer (score 1):

I can't 100% understand what you're going for, but I think your seq() might be producing strange bboxes. Is this closer? Dividing the extent of the y axis seems safer.

```
bb = st_bbox(xalver)
top <- bb['ymax']
bot <- bb['ymin']
steps <- seq(bot, top, by = (top - bot) / 10)

test <- lapply(steps[2:length(steps)], function(frame) {
  bf <- bb
  bf['ymax'] <- frame
  st_crop(xalver, st_as_sfc(bf, 4326))

})

for(i in seq_along(test)) { 
  plot(test[[i]])
  Sys.sleep(0.3)
  }
```

Either way, set `plot(x , col = NA)` and see what happens. Ref - https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/945

Comment: Its nothing to do with the structure of the code, its purely the bug you mention - which is fixed in 0.7.3 on github.

Comment: changed the col to white and it looks good; plotting does work well with geom_sf and plot.sf; i'll have to decide if it's going to be better to keep the two bounding boxes or only one in the final version of the code